# hash indexed directories

Tags: filesystems, operating-system

I was just going through the minix filesystem when I got curious about the various filesystems out there. On reading about the features that are supported by ext2 I saw that `hash indexed directories` is one among them.

Could someone enlighten me on as to what this is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the link below for details on Ext2/3 Htree directory indexing:

http://ext2.sourceforge.net/2005-ols/paper-html/node3.html

Basically the filesystem uses a hash tree to store directory entries, rather than a linear list. That results in a siginificant performance improvement in directory lookup operations.

Comment: They are used in ext4 also and can be seen with the lsattr command, but cannot figure out how to create an indexed directory.